# t-sql long query using CTE's and cross joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm facing a very weird problem where I have a complex (long) query with multiple CTE's and in the end I select values from those multiple CTE's using cross joins. Most of the time it works fine, but for some cases it's returning 0 zeros where it should return data.

Running the cte's individually I can see the data I'm looking for. Then I've started to add one cte at a time in the final cross join. I've noticed that for only one is "crashing" the results even though it's not throwing any error.

My final test, I've moved the problematic one as the first cte in my final select statement and everything is working fine (in the following query, imagine cte_e becomes the first one in the final select).

the query looks like this:

```
;with cte_a as
(
     //select
),
cte_b as
(
     //select
),
cte_c as
(
     //select
),
cte_d as
(
     //select
)
,
cte_e as
(
     //select
)

select * from
cte_a,
cte_b,
cte_c,
cte_d,
cte_e
```

Questions:

1. Is there any constrain related to type of the data when using cross joins?
2. Is there any limit related to the number of CTEs in a query?
3. How can I proper identify what is the issue with this CTE in particular?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Ok, but I don't think using JOIN will solve the issue

Comment: Hard to give much help without your queries, table structures or sample data. 5 CTEs is not unusual, most likely an issue with JOINs or data types.

Comment: Without an order by clause and without knowing the number of rows generated by each cte, perhaps the issue is that you are making assumptions based on the <undefined> order of rows in the final resultset?

Comment: Are the CTEs all independent, i.e. none references another? Does the final `select` have no `group by`, `having` or `where` clause, i.e. it is a "pure" `cross join` that should return every combination of source rows? Nothing `distinct`?

Comment: No group by in the final select, but many in the CTEs. I've changed the way I'm returning the data, rather than cross join, one value per row and now it's working as expected. Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. No - there's no constraint on the column types which may be cross joined
2. No (subject to all SQL Server maximums of course) - have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) at all of the maxes.  There's no mention of maximum number of common table expresssions.
3. Join the particular CTE to the remaining CTE's pairwise.  Somewhere there's a join condition between CTE's which returns zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the way I'm returning the data, rather than cross join, one value per row and now it's working as expected. Thank you all for trying to help.